# Drainage for stairs to garden-level basement entrance

Tags: drainage

I have some concrete stairs that go down a few feet from the back yard into a basement door.  During a heavy rain, water pools on the bottom stair, eventually coming in under the bottom of the door into the basement.

[image: Wet Basement Stairs]

The water comes down the stairs, but additionally from a gap between the house and a patio slab.  On the left of the photo,  you can see mud and some wood damage.  That mud is coming out of the gap.  (At ground level, left, is a concrete patio.)

I'm thinking that an economical way of dealing with this may be to bust up the bottom concrete stair, dig down a foot or so, and fill it with large crushed rock.  The hope is that during the rain, the water will have time to evaporate or soak into the ground before overflowing.

A couple questions:

- Is this a viable plan?
- What's the best way to bust up that bottom stair without damaging the stairs its attached to?
- Is there a better option I should be considering?

Comment: You sure there is not a plugged drain there somewhere (Outside)?  Your idea is correct, but it will take a lot more hole depth and gravel to actually work.  Water quantity builds up quick, plus there is a lot of displacement with the gravel backfill.  Divert any water you can before it gets there too.

Comment: @Tyson Yeah, there's no drain or anything, and there's nowhere downhill for it to go.  This part of the house is an addition.  Additionally, there's no basement floor drain in this room.  Closest drain in the basement is on the other side of the house.  Any guess as to how deep I'll have to dig down?  Does it make more sense to dig a foot down, bury some large perforated drainage pipe as sort of a cavity, and put the rock on top of that?

Comment: First thing is stop as much as possible from getting down there to begin with.   Creative dams, channels whatever, but get it to the point that your only stair water is literally what falls in that space. None over the edge, none from the patio etc.  that’s the most important first step.